# is it possible to iterate images in one single loop in such a way it will automatically put images inside each buttons in tkinter python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

[image]

```
db = open("products.txt", "r")
file = csv.reader(db, delimiter=',')


table = [ [col[0],col[1],col[2]] for col in file]
pos_x, pos_y, cntr = 1, 1, 0
for value in table:
    if cntr % 5 == 0:
        print(cntr)
        pos_x = pos_x + 1
        #pos_x = pos_x + 114
        pos_y = 0

    b = Button(frame, text = (value[1] ), height = 6, width = 15, command=None, anchor=S,compound=CENTER)
    b.grid(row=pos_x, column=pos_y)

    pos_y = pos_y + 1
    #pos_y = pos_y + 100
    cntr = cntr + 1
```

Comment: this code just automatically creates buttons base on what is written on the file. i used csv and now successfully created like 50+ buttons using for loop. my question is that , is it possible to iterate images too in such a way it will display images in each button created .

Comment: Put your question in the question, not a comment.

Comment: why don't you try? create a list with paths to your images, create them and apply them ...

Comment: Yes,  is it possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have image + text in one button in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15009117/how-to-have-image-text-in-one-button-in-tkinter)

Comment: thanks, i have gotten this. I just needed to create a dictionary as the variable being iterated with different image file path.